# asset img in img tag using Twig

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig

I'm working on a project with Twig, but I can't load a banner inside html in the img tag using Twig.

I have also tried to set the `src` attribute... but nothing worked out.

```
<div class="container">
  {# TODO: banner image #}
  <img src="{{ asset('storefront/img/banner-detail.jpg', '@BeckhuisNamaken')}}" alt="banner image" class="bannerImage"/>
</div>
```

I think the `src` isn't correct but I have just followed the right route of my directories

Comment: Does the `asset` function return the correct path to the image? What does the rendered output look like?

Comment: @Jerodev I only get my default error from the webshop. The rendered output should be the img banner.

Comment: I don't think the asset function takes a second parameter. What's the purpose of '@BeckhuisNamaken' here ?

Comment: @Reqven, you can set a second parameter, but in this case it was just:                 <img srcset="{{ shopware.theme['sale-banner-image'] |sw_encode_url }}" alt="banner image" class="bannerImage"/>